# T-SQL drops nulls from right side of left join when not filtering right side

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across something in SQL that I really don't understand and would also like to have a solution for. Why do nulls get filtered out from query if I don't filter the right side of the query in the join clause?

```
DECLARE @Categories table (CategoryID int, CategoryType varchar(30))
INSERT @Categories VALUES (1, 'T15')
INSERT @Categories VALUES (2, 'T15')
INSERT @Categories VALUES (3, 'T15')

DECLARE @SubCategories table (SubCategoryID int, CategoryID int, SubCategoryType varchar(30))
INSERT @SubCategories VALUES (1, 1, 'AAA A')
INSERT @SubCategories VALUES (2, 1, 'AAA B')
INSERT @SubCategories VALUES (3, 1, 'AAA C')
INSERT @SubCategories VALUES (4, 2, 'BBB A')
INSERT @SubCategories VALUES (5, 1, 'BBB A')
INSERT @SubCategories VALUES (6, 1, 'BBB B')
INSERT @SubCategories VALUES (7, 1, 'BBB C')
INSERT @SubCategories VALUES (14, 3, 'AAA B')
INSERT @SubCategories VALUES (15, 3, 'AAA C')
INSERT @SubCategories VALUES (16, 3, 'AAA A')

SELECT c.CategoryID, sc.SubCategoryType
FROM @Categories c
LEFT JOIN @SubCategories sc ON c.CategoryID = sc.CategoryID AND SubCategoryType = 'AAA A'

SELECT c.CategoryID, sc.SubCategoryType
FROM @Categories c
LEFT JOIN @SubCategories sc ON c.CategoryID = sc.CategoryID
```

```
CategoryID  SubCategoryType
----------- ------------------------------
1           AAA A
2           NULL                          This one is MIA from the other result set
3           AAA A

CategoryID  SubCategoryType
----------- ------------------------------
1           AAA A
1           AAA B
1           AAA C
1           BBB A
1           BBB B
1           BBB C
2           BBB A
3           AAA B
3           AAA C
3           AAA A
```

I'm expecting to see the second row of the first query in the second query, but it isn't there. Why, and how can I get it there?

Comment: LEFT JOIN... AND (SubCategoryType = 'AAA A'  OR SubCategoryType IS NULL) --totally off

Comment: The `ON` clauses aren't the same, why would you expect the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NULL`s are not being "filtered out".

There is a match in values between the two tables.  That is what the second query is telling you.  However, the match is on `'BBB A'`.  There is no match on `'AAA A'`.

Your first query reflects that.  It is saying "only consider matches on `'AAA A'`".  Because there is no such match, the query returns `NULL` for that row.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Is there a neat way to go through different subcategories and assign them to the first query, so I could get all the nulls also?

Comment: @Roihu . . . I would suggest that you ask a NEW question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to check `SubCategoryType` `'AAA A'` is missing :

```
SELECT c.CategoryID, sc.SubCategoryType
FROM @Categories c LEFT JOIN 
     @SubCategories sc 
     ON c.CategoryID = sc.CategoryID
UNION ALL
SELECT c.CategoryID, NULL
FROM @Categories c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM @SubCategories sc 
                  WHERE sc.CategoryID = c.CategoryID AND sc.SubCategoryType = 'AAA A'
                 )
ORDER BY CategoryID;
```